# Jest + MockImplementationOnce + is not working for 2nd time

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using JEST framework for unit testing for my node.js project. I Used `mockImplementationOnce` for mocking thirdParty library methods as follows:

```
jest.mock('abc', () => {
    return { a: { b: jest.fn() } };
  });
const abcjs= require('abc');

describe("1st test", () => { 
  test("should return true", async () => {
    abcjs.a.b.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(
      return true}
    ));
  });
});

describe("2nd test", () => { 
  test("should return false", async () => {
    abcjs.a.b.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(
      return false}
    ));
  });
});
```

1st test was executed successfully, but the **2nd test Its calling the actual method, its not mocking.**
I tried resetting the mocks `afterEach` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same issue yesterday with mocking aws-sdk.

It turned out that after you have mocked a whole module once, you can't override the behaviour of that mock in the same file again.

**I am surprised that your first test actually passed, even though your default mock function was simply a jest.fn() without any return value.**

There is a whole discussion here on this - https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582

Final Solution from the thread:

```js
// no mocking of the whole module

const abcjs= require('abc');


describe("1st test", () => { 
  test("should return true", async () => {

    // Try using jest.spyOn() instead of jest.fn

    jest.spyOn(abcjs.a,'b').mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(true)));
    //expect statement here
  });
});

describe("2nd test", () => { 

jest.restoreAllMocks(); // <----------- remember to add this

  test("should return false", async () => {
    jest.spyOn(abcjs.a,'b').mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(false)));
    // expect statement here
  });
});
```

Basically, DON'T mock the whole module but instead only mock the functions you want from it.

Comment: Still i am receiving the same error. Now i am receiving the error in my 1st test case itself.

Comment: now for 2nd test its shows undefined of the mocked method while calling the ctrl funciotn.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use `jest.spyOn` instead of `jest.fn` and tag on `mockImplementationOnce` at the end like shown here - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: Actually i am experimeting with spyOn. But still for 2nd test its not mocking. Its calling the actual method. Also whetehr we need to add jest.restoreAllMocks(); as it is OR afterEach kind of thing??

Comment: `jest.restoreAllMocks` reverts the function to its original functionality before it was ever mocked. So, you can put it in `afterEach` if you like. Also, as long as you are mocking your function a second time, your second test should pass as well. Can you update your code in your question?

Comment: I am having implementattion as same like your answer.

Comment: there is a typo in your original code around `promise.resolve` in both fake function implementations, don't know if thats a copy/paste error or an actual error. You also dont have any `expect` calls in your code

Comment: Ya its a typo.But still i am facing the same error.

Comment: Any idea why its calling the actula method for the seconfd time??

Comment: I will need to see your code (including your assertions) to see whats going wrong.

Comment: This is very useful. I spent a lot of time for this: 'after you have mocked a whole module once, you can't override the behaviour of that mock in the same file again.' This should be in jest docs..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be a reference for you. If it's me, then the idea looks like this:

Think of it as the third party library method you are referring to.

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
const abcjs = {
    a: { b: () => null }
}
```

then the test scenario that I imagine is ...

```
describe('a test scenario', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // Restores all mocks back to their original value.
        // only works when the mock was created with jest.spyOn;
        jest.restoreAllMocks()
    })

    describe('1st test', () => {
        test('should return true', async () => {
            jest.spyOn(abcjs.a, 'b').mockImplementation()
            /**
              * Accepts a value that will be returned for one call to the mock function. Can be chained so that
              * successive calls to the mock function return different values. When there are no more
              * `mockResolvedValueOnce` values to use, calls will return a value specified by `mockResolvedValueOnce`. 
              */
            abcjs.a.b.mockResolvedValueOnce(true).mockResolvedValueOnce('isTrue')

            let resultExpected = await abcjs.a.b()
            
            // Ensures that a mock function is called an exact number of times.          
            expect(abcjs.a.b).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
            // Used when you want to check that two objects have the same value.
            expect(resultExpected).toEqual(true)

            // try to invoked the function for second times...
            resultExpected = await abcjs.a.b()

            // Ensures that a mock function is called an exact number of times...
            // which is the second time !
            expect(abcjs.a.b).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
            // Used when you want to check that two objects have the same value.
            expect(resultExpected).toEqual('isTrue')
        })
    })

    describe('2nd test', () => {
        test('should return false', async () => {
            jest.spyOn(abcjs.a, 'b').mockImplementation()
            abcjs.a.b.mockResolvedValueOnce(false)

            const resultExpected = await abcjs.a.b()

            expect(abcjs.a.b).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
            expect(resultExpected).toEqual(false)
        })
    })
})
```

If it was me, I prefer to return the promise using this
`mockFn.mockResolvedValue(value)` or `mockFn.mockRejectedValue(value)` [see the doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue)  instead of `mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(value))`

This is just one approach to testing that I can describe. Hopefully this will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I needed to call async on the it block, and await on my function. It then worked. e.g.

```
it('should call', async() => {
  await function(); 

  expect('1').toHaveBeenCalledWith({})
});
```

^ something like that

Comment: Was banging my head of the wall for an hour wondering why my second invocation was being called on the actual object while the first was working correctly on the mock. This was it for me as well, forget to await the call to the method which invokes the mock. Thanks!